# Update Join Query not Updating Record in The Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my attendance table I want to update a record with `S_ID` and `C_ID` from `StudentCourse` bridge table but its not updating.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMPPo.jpg

Its working when I use it to select and display 2 columns from the `StudentCourse` table and 1 column from the `Attendance` table but it doesn't work when I use it to update the attendance table which for now is empty

```
    UPDATE Attendance
    SET S_ID = sc.S_ID,
    C_ID = sc.C_ID
    FROM Attendance a
    left outer join StudentCourse sc ON a.S_ID = sc.S_ID
    WHERE sc.S_ID=2 and sc.C_ID=2
```

[image]

There are two actually four tables:

- Student(S_ID(primary key))
- Course(C_ID(Primary key))
- StudentCourse((S_ID,C_ID(Foreign keys))Bridge table)
- and attendance table with (S_ID,C_ID(Foreign keys))

What I am doing is displaying data on `datagridview` by joining tables and selecting `S_ID`,`S_Name`,`C_ID` and `Pre_Abs` (`Attendance` table column)columns from all these tables.

Now, I want to insert the info present in `datagridview` to the attendance table when I click on button.

I have done this already with simple insert query to attendance table by using `datagrdview.rows[i].cell[2]` property.

I want to know if there is any better idea to do this so that I can use `JOIN` instead of using `datagridview` property with for loop.

For now my attendance table is empty while `Student`, `Course`, and `StudentCourse` tables are filled with the data.

What I want is to display record(`S_ID`, `C_ID`) from `studentCourse` table and (`Pre_Abs`) from `Attendance` table and when I submit the attendance; I want it to store `Pre_abs` record against each `S_ID`, `C_ID` in the attendance table.

[image]

I don't think I can explain it any further.

Comment: It's an outer join, so `sc.S_ID` will be `NULL`, so your where clause fails for all rows in `Attendance`. Also, if attendance is empty... what (nonexisting) record do you expect to update?

Comment: is it not possible to update it with the record that is already present in StudentCourse table.if not then what's the solution for it?btw i tried using all joins none worked for my problem..what's the use of foreign key if i can't use it to update attendance table columns with StudentCourse table columns

Comment: do i need to use insert query for this purpose?

Comment: Bingo ;) `Update` just changes existing data

Comment: thanks will you help me to write insert query for this particular function to get it to working i really dont know how to write insert query with a join

Comment: insert into Attendance
  SELECT
     StudentCourse.S_ID, 
     StudentCourse.C_ID 
  FROM StudentCourse
  left JOIN Student on StudentCourse.S_ID = Student.S_ID
   left JOIN Course on StudentCourse.C_ID = Course.C_ID

  where StudentCourse.S_ID='2' and StudentCourse.C_ID='2'  this is also not working

Comment: Why do you want to select from an empty table anyway? Why a join if you want to insert into a from b?

Comment: didnt give it much of thought..you are right JOIN doesnt make sense when Attendance table is empty

Comment: Still not able to get what i want now i can select only those rows that match in both tables while i want to updte S_ID,C_ID,Date,Pre_Abs from Attendance table then i want to update it with the values that are selected and showed from StudentCourse table in datagridview in c#

Comment: insert into Attendance(S_ID,C_ID,Pre_Abs)
select a.Pre_Abs,sc.S_ID,sc.C_ID from Attendance a,StudentCourse sc
 join Student s on s.S_ID=sc.S_ID
 join Course c on c.C_ID=sc.C_ID
where sc.S_ID=2 and sc.C_ID=2
this is also not working...

Answer (score 0):

You have declared alias for the table Attendance. So you should use alias reference before the column name as the same column name also available in other table. Can you please try this-

```
UPDATE a
SET a.S_ID = sc.S_ID,
a.C_ID = sc.C_ID
FROM Attendance a
LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentCourse sc ON a.S_ID = sc.S_ID
WHERE sc.S_ID=2 and sc.C_ID=2
```

I have also doubt about you where condition as you are Update table Attendance but filtering records on table StudentCourse. use of wrong filter can resultant in update all rows in table Attendance. Please be careful.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i think problem was due to the fact that i was using wrong query i.e update instead of insert.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I do not understand the reason why your `Attendance` table exists in the first place. Your `StudentCourse` table already seems to contain info about which students are having which courses. I'll just assume the `Attendance` table has to deal with registering student attendance for each single lecture/lesson within a course.

Anyway, as @Psi already commented, you seem to initially want an INSERT query to create a record in the `Attendance` table with data based on information in the `StudentCourse` table. I guess that you are thinking about it too hard. ;-) You may try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Attendance (S_ID, C_ID, Pre_Abs)
SELECT S_ID, C_ID, Pre_Abs
FROM StudentCourse
WHERE S_ID = 2 AND C_ID = 2
```

However, it is currently unclear how field `Pre_Abs` should be filled... You try to get it from table `Attendance`, but that would seem to be invalid.

Also, when creating INSERT-queries, make sure that the source data values (in the SELECT or VALUES clause) are in the same order as the target fields (in the INSERT clause). If the field/value order doesn't match, the data gets mixed up (if the query does not fail due to data type errors)!

And last but not least: if both `Attendance` and `StudentCourse` tables share the same composite key `(S_ID, C_ID)`, you should use that full key when joining related records of those tables:

```
FROM
    Attendance AS A
    LEFT JOIN StudentCourse AS SC ON
        SC.S_ID = A.S_ID AND
        SC.C_ID = A.C_ID
```

Hope this helps a little...

Comment: i got it working...i know the mistakes that i was making.now i want to ask why you said that i dont attendance table?how am i suppose to record attendance of each student with different course id daily?do you think attendance table is not required logically?what should i do then?

Comment: Ah. So the table is indeed used for daily (or per-lecture/lesson) registrations. Then it's OK. Just forget my remarks regarding that table then.